# Android ReST based client and SOAP server. Is it possible?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, soap

I'm writing a web-service for Android. The client side will be coded in JAVA and we are planning on using ReST. But, the server supports SOAP, JMS( Java Messaging Service) and Remote Method Invocation (only these). I just want to know if it is possible to return response for a ReST based client from this server.

As far as I know, ReST is not a protocol like SOAP, but I just want to be sure that it can be done before I get started.

Any link to video/tutorial/code will also do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is really just an elegant way to use HTTP for resource access.
HTTP is the protocol.
So if you can process HTTP requests on that server, it's doable.
In a Java EE environment a servlet container is perfect: you can create a WAR based on the Jersey framework.

Comment: That answered the question! 
Thanks a lot